# How to establish n:1-relation with Razor/Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, relationship, .net-7.0

I'm working with VS 2022 for Mac 17.6. My current project is Razor web app with .NET 7.0 and Entity Framework with SQLite.

This is what I want to achieve: in my data model I have, among others, two tables `EventInstance` and `Note`. Several rows in `EventInstance` are related to one row in `Note`. Whenever user edits one `EventInstance`, changes to the linked `Note` are supposed to appear as well in all other `EventInstances` related to the same row.

This is part of my data model as of now:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<EventInstance>()
                .HasOne(i => i.Note)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.NoteId);
}
    
public class EventInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Spezifikation")]
    public required string Specification { get; set; }

    // ... 

    public int? NoteId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Notiz")]
    public Note? Note { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Notiz"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string? Content { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Create.cshtml.cs` everything seem to work fine. I have manually coded these lines:

```
Note note = new Note() { Content = "" };

_context.Note.Add(note);
_context.SaveChanges();

int noteId = note.Id;
```

After creating a new `EventInstance`, I can check in the database that a new row in `Event` has been added and assigned an `Id`.

This is my EXISTING EditModel / PageModel für EventInstance:

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorPagesSchedule.Data.ScheduleDbContext _context;

    public EditModel(RazorPagesSchedule.Data.ScheduleDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public EventInstance EventInstance { get; set; } = default!;

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.EventInstance == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var eventinstance = await _context.EventInstance
            .Include(i => i.EventTemplate)
            .Include(i => i.ResponsiblePerson)
            .Include(i => i.Note)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (eventinstance == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        EventInstance = eventinstance;

        var list = new SelectList(_context.EventTemplate, "Id", "Description").ToList();
        list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--- Keine Aufgabenvorlage ---", Value = "" });
        ViewData["EventTemplateId"] = list;
        var persons = new SelectList(_context.Person.OrderBy(p => p.Sn), "Id", "Sn");
        ViewData["ResponsiblePersonId"] = persons;
        return Page();
    }

    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Attach(EventInstance).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EventInstanceExists(EventInstance.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool EventInstanceExists(int id)
    {
      return (_context.EventInstance?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
    }
}
```

EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR: When editing an Event, no new row in Note is to be created, but the existing linked row ought to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you should be loading the entity from the DB and modify it instead of taking it from the client verbatim, but the reason it’s creating a new Note is that you don’t tell it it’s modified. Add this:

```cs
_context.Attach(EventInstance.Note).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

To be safe, probably do a null check for `Note` first and be sure its Id is > 0. Really, you need to check that the Id actually exists, or you’ll get a foreign key exception.

You also need the Note’s Id in your form:

```html
<input asp-for="@Model.EventInstance.Note.Id" hidden />
```

Be aware it must be `Note.Id` not `NoteId`, as the latter would try to save a Note with Id 0, which would normally add a new row, but will crash when set to `EntityState.Modified`.

Comment: That worked like a charm. If you were near, I'd offer you a beer ;-)
Can you elaborate on "loading the entity from the DB and modify it"? Any link where I can read about this technique? Is it more safe than my approach?

Comment: Thanks for the accept, glad it works! I mean like they do it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-8.0#update-the-edit-page (same article as in your comment regarding overposting). Basically fetch the existing entity from the database, make only the permissible modifications and call `SaveChanges`. This spares you from manually messing with the change tracking, prevents overposting and ensures you’re working with current DB state (e.g. the record may have been deleted between GET and POST. Maybe the user loaded the form and went to lunch).